# How to tag questions about databases of mathematical objects?

Tags: discussion, tags

On MO there were several questions regarding databases of (some type of) mathematical objects. You can see the list of questions I was able to find [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32225011#32225011).

What would be correct tag for such questions? I can think of three possible answers which seem to be reasonable (at least to some extent)

- We could use the [online-resources](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/online-resources) tag.
- We could create an entirely new tag for such questions
- It does not really matter.

---

Let me first say that I think that using correct tags is useful. Tags help with searching, although in this case it is very likely that the question will contain the word "database" or "databases", so probably the tags will not improve the search that much for this type of questions. But the tags are also used in [the algorithm which selects the list of related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions-l) (shown for each question in the sidebar on the right). If the questions with similar focus have similar tags, this might improve that list and thus help the askers to see whether similar questions have been asked in the past.

I am not really sure that creating a new tag is a good option. Mainly for the reason that there are at most 5 tags per questions, so it is not good to create too small tags for things which fit nicely under some moderately large tag,

So my personal preference is to use [online-resources](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/online-resources). As you can see in the list of the questions linked above, it seems that this is (in most cases) consistent with the tagging of questions about this topic so far. However, one possible objection for using this tag might be that such a database *need not be online.* (For example, suppose that somebody asks "Can I find somewhere all groups with the following property together with their character table?" Then this would be a valid answer which would not include any online resource: "Such list can be generated in GAP using the following commands...")

I have also [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/69628) the [tag-wiki for online-resources](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/online-resources/info) where I explicitly mentioned databases of mathematical objects. Of course, further improvements to the tag-wiki which might help to clarify the usage of this tag are welcome.

**TL;DR:** How should questions about databases of mathematical objects be tagged? (What do you think about the three options mentioned above. Are there some other reasonable possibilities?)